# Conditional density along a curve?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be two random variables with $f_{X,Y}$ as their joint pdf and with $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ as their marginal pdf's. The conditional pdf of, say $X$ with respect to $Y$ is $$f_{X\mid Y=y}(x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}.$$

Then $$P(u<X<v\mid Y=y)=\int_u^vf_{X\mid Y=y}(x)dx.\tag 1$$
The following figure helps understand another interpretation of the same conditional probability.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvbzo.png]

Here $A$ and $a=\{(x,y): x\in \mathbb R\}$ are measurable sets of $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R.$ $a$ is a curve given in parametric form, and if $u<x<v$ then $(x,y)\in A$.

With this, the conditional probability above can be written as

$$P((X,Y)\in A\mid (X,Y)\in a)=\int_u^vf_{X\mid Y=y}(x)dx.\tag 2$$
If one was shown (2), the one would argue that because of $P((X,Y) \in a)=0$ (2) is undefined. Apparently, however, we are talking about the same conditional probabilities under (1) and (2).

Now, let's take a look at the following figure:

[image]

where $a=\{(x,y):x=x(s),y=y(s), s\in \mathbb R \}$, that is, $a$ is a curve given in parametric form and if $u\le s \le v$ then $(x,y)\in A.$

If I presented one the conditional probability

$$P((X,Y)\in A\mid (X,Y)\in a) \tag 3$$

the one would say that the conditional probability above is meaningless because $P((X,Y)\in a)=0$.

This time I cannot defend myself by pointing at some marginal pdf's and at the corresponding conditional pdf's. Why is that so?

> Or how could I set up a parallel theory establishing the validity of (3)?

Comment: Just a thought... not sure if this helps. Suppose in the second case the curve had equation $f(x,y)=c$ for some given $c$. Then what if we define a random variable $Z=f(X,Y)$? And then the required conditional probability would be $P(X\in A\mid Z=c)$, which could be dealt with as in the first case with $P(X\in A\mid Y=a)$?